# How come for some Univ3 swaps, the price of the pool after a buy is *lower* than the price paid for the swap? This should not be possible

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

First off, I'm fully aware of concentrated liquidity on Univ3. This is not a question about that.

Regardless of concentrated liquidity or not, it is my understanding that the swap price a Buyer is getting should always be lower than the price the pool ends up at after the swap, simply because you buy along a curve.

Some swaps do not seem to have this behavior. Take for instance the swap [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x52f7d086dd706b4e45ac00c9e2652c0f7499545784d4059e3e4f73ad54c1d7c8#eventlog)

```
amount0 :-1279211354315689962871
amount1 :13000000000000000
sqrtPriceX96 :251314635170608008427270616
liquidity :43887562687655428171896
tick :-115074
```

Here token1 = ETH / token 0 = Party.
Someone bought 1279.21 PARTY for 0.013 ETH, which amounts to `0.013/127921 = 0.00001016251` ETH/Party

However, the price ETH/Party after the swap is **lower** instead of higher, as calculated by: `sqrtPriceX96^2 / 2^192 = 0.000010061`.

I.e; price of pool ~1% lower after a buy, then the price the buyer got.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding on the prices is correct. Token's price after a swap that  buys the token from the pool (`P_end`) is strictly greater than the initial price in the pool (`P_start`), and the average the price the swap is executed, which is equal to the `P_swap = sqrt(P_start * P_end)`.

But your price calculation from the swap event is wrong. The `amount0` and `amount1` ratio from the [swap event also includes](https://%20https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/core/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolEvents#swap) fees paid by the buyer.

The actual amount of ETH used to buy the token is 99% of the transferred amount:

```
>>> 13000000000000000 * 99 // 100
12870000000000000
```

The price is `P_swap = 12870000000000000 / 1279211354315689962871 = 1.0060886308255734e-05` which is less than `P_end = 1.006181650599695e-05`:

```
>>> 1.0060886308255734e-05 < 1.006181650599695e-05
True
```